# How to make Django 'listen' for file uploads to FTP server

Tags: python, django, ftp

I have a Django application that manages orders from a Shopify-based webshop. Whenever someone orders something that needs shipping, my app will create a file and place it on the carriers ftp-server. When the order has been shipped, the carrier will upload a new file to the ftp-server with the relevant information about the shipment.

How can I make Django automatically 'listen' for these file uploads? I have looked a bit at [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), but it doesn't say anything about ftp interaction. Can this be done and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wouldn't be an appropriate use of channels, which is about interaction via Websockets with the user's browser.

You probably don't need anything complicated though. The easiest thing would be a cron job every few minutes, which runs a Django command to check the FTP directory and trigger actions as necessary.